# Little confusion about connectedness

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness

Consider $X=\{(x,\sin(1/x)):0<x<1\}$. Then clearly $X$ is connected , as it is a continuous image of the connected set $(0,1)$.

So, $\overline X$ is also connected , as closure of connected set is connected.

Now if we notice about the set $\overline X$ then

$$\overline X=X\cup B$$

where , $B=\{(0,y):-1\le y\le 1\}$
Now , $X$ and $B$ both are connected , and $X\cap B=\emptyset$ . So, $\overline X$ is disconnected.

Where my mistake ??

Comment: The closure doesn't contain $C$.

Comment: Being not connected is more than disjoint, otherwise all sets with at least two elements would be not connected. Any open set containing $B$ must contain an open set around $(0,0)$ and hence intersect $X$.

Comment: Why such a complicated example?. Here's a simpler one. $[0,2]=[0,1)\cup[1,2].$ Now, $[0,1)$ and $[1,2]$ are both connected, and $[0,1)\cap[1,2]=\emptyset.$ Now I guess you think it follows that $[0,2]$ is disconnected. Why do you think that follows? What definition or theorem are you using?

Comment: Actually my confusion arise from this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment you mentioned the following correct theorem:

**Theorem**: If $A$ and $B$ are connected and $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$ then $A \cup B$ is connected.

You might have confused this with the below converse, which is false:

**False**: If $A$ and $B$ are connected and $A \cap B = \varnothing$ then $A \cup B$ is not connected.

Counterexamples have been given in other answers, such as $A = (0;1]$ and $B=\{0\}$.

In order to make this statement true, you need $A$ and $B$ to be not only disjoint, but separated by disjoint open sets, i.e., that there exist open disjoint sets $X \supset A$ and $Y \supset B$.

You can also separate them by closed sets, which leads to the following correct theorem:

**Theorem**: If $A$ and $B$ are connected and non-empty, and $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \varnothing$ then $A \cup B$ is not connected.

Comment: When you say "contrapositive" (which would be an equivalent reformulation, which it is not) you mean "converse" (I'm not sure it really is a converse, but the term converse has no precise definition anyway).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks, fixed. It can be viewed as a converse if you fix the "$A$ and $B$ are connected" part. I hope the use of the expression "the below converse" as opposed to "its converse" is good enough.

Comment: I think your last statement can be strengthened to: "if $A$ and $B$ are connected and either $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} = \varnothing$ or $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} \not\subseteq A \cup B$, then $A \cup B$ is not connected."

Comment: @A.P. Not really. Consider $B = A \neq \overline{A}$.

Comment: @A.P.  Maybe you wanted "If $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \cap (A \cup B) = \varnothing$, then $A \cup B$ is not connected", but then you only need $A$ and $B$ to be nonempty, and you can replace $A \cup B$ by an arbitrary set $X$ intersecting both $\overline{A}$ and $\overline{B}$. This gives you the most general statement that can be made about connected sets =).

Comment: Indeed, I wanted $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} \cap (A \cup B) = \varnothing$. I don't think your second statement is true, though. If I could replace $A \cup B$ with an arbitrary set $X$ intersecting both $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$, then I could choose $X = \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}$, getting the condition $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} \cap X = \bar{A} \cap \bar{B} = \varnothing$, which is weaker than the one with $A \cup B$. For example, consider $A = (0,1)$ and $B = (1,2)$. Then $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} = \{1\} \not \subseteq A \cup B$ and $A \cup B$ is not connected.

Answer (score 5):

The set $B$  is NOT open, so this is not a partition of $\overline X$ in open sets.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ both are connected..What is necessary condition to $A\cup B$ be connected?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: It is certainly necessary that not both $A$ and $B$ are open in $A\cup B$. If both are open, then $A\cup B$ is disconnected. But this is independent of $A$ or $B$ being connected.

Comment: @ Stefan Hamcke ): If $A$ and $B$ are two non-empty connected open sets (OR closed sets ) then $A\cup B$ is open **if and only if** $A\cap B \not =\emptyset$. Is it??? I think it is true...

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 I think you mean "$A \cup B$ is *connected*"... the union of two open sets is always open.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Anyway, if *both* $A$ and $B$ are either open or closed, then it is true that $A \cup B$ is connected iff $A \cap B \neq \varnothing$. This can fail, though, if for example $A$ is open and $B$ is closed, which is the case for $A = (0,1)$, $B = [1,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your reasoning there is two incorrectness:

1. We have $\overline{X}=X\cup B\cup\{(1,\sin(1))\}$.
2. The implication :

   **$X$ and $B$ are connected and $X\cap B=\emptyset$ $\Rightarrow$ $X\cup B$
   is not connected**

is false. For a counterexample one can see that $\{0\}$ and $(0,1]$ are connected and disjoint, and $\{0\}\cup(0,1]=[0,1]$ is also connected.

Comment: So, in the theorem " If $A$ and $B$ are connected and $A\cap B\not =\emptyset$ then $A\cup B$ is connected " is the condition of **non-empty**  sufficient ?

Comment: Can you be more clear?

Comment: **Theorem:** " If $A$ and $B$ are connected and $A\cap B\not =\emptyset$ then $A\cup B$ is connected

Comment: In the above theorem is  the condition $A\cap B\not =\emptyset$  sufficient ??

Comment: The Theorem is ok, I don't understand what do you mean by: ''is the condition of non-empty sufficient ?''

Comment: That means , if $A$ and $B$ both are connected and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ then $A\cup B$ can be connected ?

Comment: Yes. See the counterexample in my answer.

Comment: Yes...I saw that...But what is the necessary condition to $A\cup B$ be connected ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 The necessary condition is that $A\cup B$ cannot be written as the union of nonempty deisjoint open sets.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is an error for $\overline{X}$. You have $\overline{X} = X \cup B$. "The curve is not oscillating on the right side"